# Data not showing in the API (NodeJS + Express)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, express, mongoose

I am developing a sample API for restaurants in which I want retrieve data of restaurants by entering the Restaurant's name. Controller, Model & Router has been set but if I load it into Postman data doesn't appear. Please share some ideas.

Controller: (restaurant.js)

```
const restaurants = require('../Models/restaurantData');
exports.getRestaurantName = (req, res) => {
    const Name = req.params.name;    
    restaurants.find({
        name: Name
    }).then(result => {
        res.status(200).json({
            message: "Restaurant Data",
            restaurants: result[0]
        });
    }).catch(error => {
        res.status(500).json({
            message: error
        });
    });
}
```

Model: (restaurantData.js)

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const restaurantSchema = new Schema({
    _id: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    city_name:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    city_id: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    location_id: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    area: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    locality:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    thumb: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    cost:{
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    address:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    mealtype:{
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    name:{
        type: String,
            required: true
        },    
    cuisine:{
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    type:{
        type: Array,
        required: true
    },
    Cuisine:{
        type: Array,
        required: true
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('restaurantData', restaurantSchema, 'restaurantData');
```

Router:

```
const express = require('express');
const restaurantController = require('../Controllers/restaurant');

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/restaurantData/:name',restaurantController.getRestaurantName);

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: are you able to see name `req.params.name` in console that you passed in url?

Comment: Yes, the name is showing in console

Comment: What does `console.log(result)` log inside your `.then()` handler?

Comment: The name is showing in that too.

Comment: What do you mean? It should log an array of all found documents that match the given name.

Comment: It just showing the restaurant name not its data in console.

Comment: Is there any data in your mongodb? What is your collection name in your mongodb?

Comment: All data is in MongoDB. Collection Name is restaurantData.

Answer (score 0):

Change the following and I hope it will work.
In Restaurant Model, remove this:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model(  "restaurantData",  restaurantSchema,  "restaurantData");
```

And add this:

```
const Restaurant = mongoose.model("restaurantData", restaurantSchema);
module.exports = { Restaurant };
```

In your Restaurant controller, change the import script into:

```
const { Restaurant } = require("../Models/restaurantData");
```

And Method will be:

```
Restaurant.find({
    name: Name,
  })
```

Change the variable and file names according to your need.

Comment: Did you change the names correctly. I updated the names according to your db. try again.

Comment: Changed the correctly but still not working

Answer (score 0):

had you add network access if yes then use `Model.create(req.body(err,data)={ res.send(data); })`

Comment: Where? In model, controller or router ?

Comment: `app.post('/post',(req,res)=>{
    Model.create(req.body(err,data)={ res.send(data); })
})`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be while creating the model out of the schema

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('restrauntData', restaurantSchema);
```

use the above instead of

```
module.exports = mongoose.model(  "restaurantData",  restaurantSchema,  "restaurantData");
```

then it should work fine.

Comment: This answer is exactly the same as the answer below.